# extending an interface question Typescript/js

Tags: typescript

I have to create a shape interface that has four field 
three numbers and a view I think i can do this with two interfaces and extending the one ,the view i need to be able to be undefined as all shapes dont always have a view. The view itself has properties indexShape , height ,
and moveToFront . Since every shape is not displayed on every level, the view may be undefined I have the below code but i am unsure if this is the correct way?? any help would be appreciated new to typescript

```
    interface view{
    indexShape?:any;
    height?:number;
    moveToFront?:any;
}

interface shape extends view{
numerator: number;
denominator: number;
dropZone: number;

};
```

Comment: *interface that has four field three numbers and a view* Missing mapping of view, I guess. Also, if you extend, you are inheriting all properties. This is helpful when `view` can be inheritted to more than one `shape` interface. If not, I'd suggest `IShape { view?: view; ... }`. Also note **I** infront of interface name. That is a good convention. So it should be `interface IShape extends IView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all shapes dont always have a view.

So, there is no inheritance.

```
interface View {
  indexShape: any;
  height: number;
  moveToFront: any;
}

interface Shape {
  view?: View;
  numerator: number;
  denominator: number;
  dropZone: number;
}
```

Comment: @mKalita I'm happy to help. Do not forget to [validate my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/347228).